# rm: cannot remove ‘test/deployment/sandbox-v2/tmp/dns’: Permission denied

Tags: linux, github, kubernetes, centos, sandbox

I am unable to delete ‘test/deployment/sandbox-v2/tmp/dns’ after deleting the github repository 'test'. I am unable to reclone it in my CentOS system. Even after recloning in other folder,running site.yml file of sandbox fails at logs. So i'm trying to completely remove test repository and reclone it for fresh run. I have tried all ways and commands to remove it, it gets removed as well but then gets recreated automatically with this file mentioned. Any clue how to completely remove it and clone a fresh repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say but if this was bind-mounted into a container and that container was running its process as root (uid 0) then files it created would be owned by uid 0 even outside the container. Gotta get your `sudo` on.

Comment: yes, you're right there was a coredns docker running in root mode. So, i had to stop and remove it, then it works the way i want.

Comment: @mac_55, does it answer your question ? If so, please take a quick look at the following article in Help Center: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Is dns a symlink to something within /etc that the user has no right to modify/delete?
If you go into the "test/deployment/sandbox-v2/tmp/" and do "ls -l" what does it say?
If the file is a symlink, unlink it with "unlink dns" and now you should be able to delete the file structure from the "test" directory.